# How can i setup a batch script as **cronjob** to run each time when the servers in WEST come up after a reboot

Tags: shell, cron

I run the below scp commands manually from EAST server1 when the WEST server1 and server2 are brought up after maintenance.

```
scp -i /u01/westkey.txt /u01/east_config/.keystore server1-west.com:/u01/config/.keystore
scp -i /u01/westkey.txt /u01/east_config/.keystore server2-west.com:/u01/config/.keystore
```

How can i setup this below script as **cronjob** to run each time when the servers in WEST come up after a reboot from EAST source server from where i run the scp commands using the bash script.

I know we can use @reboot command in cronjob but this will only work when the server it is running on comes up after a reboot.

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

```
 #!/bin/bash

echo "########Starting copy of keystore from EAST to server1 WEST #########";

scp -i /u01/westkey.txt /u01/east_config/.keystore server1-west.com:/u01/config/.keystore

echo "########Copy complete for server1 WEST #########";

echo "########Starting copy of keystore from EAST to server2 WEST #########";
scp -i /u01/westkey.txt /u01/east_config/.keystore server2-west.com:/u01/config/.keystore
echo "########Copy complete for server2 WEST #########";
```

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Comment: `if [ "$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 "$HOST" echo UP 2>/dev/null)" = UP ]; then`  I use this in some scripts to check if a particular host is up.  Will it work for you?

Comment: Thanks @KenJackson.

Comment: Just to confirm, does the below script look ok:                                              
`#!/bin/bash
if [ "$(ssh -o ConnectTimeout=1 "server1-west.com" echo UP 2>/dev/null)" = UP ];
then
echo "########Starting copy of keystore from EAST to server1 WEST #########";
scp -i /u01/westkey.txt /u01/east_config/.keystore server1-west.com:/u01/config/.keystore
scp -i /u01/westkey.txt /u01/east_config/.keystore server2-west.com:/u01/config/.keystore
else
echo "WEST serves are not UP";`

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted this solution from your comment above.

```
#!/bin/bash
idf="-i /u01/westkey.txt"
to="-o ConnectTimeout=1"
copying="######## Copying keystore from EAST to"
for host in server1-west.com server2-west.com; do
    if [ "$(ssh "$to" "$idf" "$host" echo UP 2>/dev/null)" = UP ]; then
        echo "$copying $host #########"
        scp "$idf" /u01/east_config/.keystore "$host":/u01/config/
    else
        echo "Server $host is down"
    fi
done
```

I added a loop so you can test each server before copying.

I added variables `$to`, `$idf` and `$copying` just to make the statements more compact and appealing.

The `if` statement executes an `echo` command on the remote server via `ssh` and captures the output with the `$( )` syntax for comparison.

Note that I've never used the `-i` option with `ssh` or `scp`.  I use the `keychain` package.  You might want to consider using it.  With it, you only need to enter your passphrase once at boot up and it maintains it in memory in a long-lived process, which is helpful for use with cron.  You just need to source the appropriate file in `~/.keychain/` in your cron script.